# What do the various locked door colors mean?

Tags: the-escapists

It seems that there are a variety of different locked door types in game:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What do these different colors mean and how do I open each different kind of door?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open these doors, you need to get a key of the same colour.

You can get the keys from guards or from prisoner stashes. Be warned, though - you need to make a [copy](http://theescapists.gamepedia.com/Plastic_Key) of the key, if you take it from a guard, else they will notice.

The key copy also has limited use, so plan accordingly.

Comment: The plastic key is the copied key. IDK if you can find a real key.

Comment: Also, the plastic key will get the colour of the original key.